# Should standard OAuth endpoints/configuration files be kept private?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

Considering an attacker may be able to leverage the information gathered from standard endpoints/configuration files such as `/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` and `/.well-known/openid-configuration`, is it considered best practice to not allow them to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Did you look this up at all?

Comment: It's also relevant to mention [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're placed at a *standard* location **because** they are required to be publicly accessible.

It's not a security weakness; it's literally a requirement for the systems to work. They do not reveal any information that an attacker can use in a properly configured system.

For instance `openid-configuration` [merely contains a list of endpoints](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfigurationResponse) and metadata about the configuration. This is information the client need, but there's no secret information.

Answer (score 1):

If you looked up [the documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8414.html), you would find:

> 3. Obtaining Authorization Server Metadata
>
> Authorization servers supporting metadata MUST make a JSON document containing metadata as specified in Section 2 available at a path formed by inserting a well-known URI string into the authorization server's issuer identifier between the host component and the path component, if any.  By default, the well-known URI string used is "/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server".  This path MUST use the > "https" scheme...

Comment: FYI: I found this in less than a minute by googling those paths in your question. Alongside the RFC, I found guides from providers that also explain why these need to be public. Please make sure to do at least a little research before posting questions here.